# How to keep Cell IndentLevel and AutoFit RowHeight - simultaneously?

Tags: excel, vba

Once more about cell formatting

```
cell.EntireRow.WrapText = True
cell.EntireRow.AutoFit
cell.IndentLevel = 1   ' AutoFit is discarded
```

Or reverse

```
cell.IndentLevel = 1
cell.EntireRow.WrapText = True
cell.EntireRow.AutoFit    ' IndentLevel is discarded
```

So, is it possible to keep cell IndentLevel and RowHeight AutoFit - together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set both `RowHeight` and `ColumnWidth`.

For some reason, it seems Column auto fit works if column width starts out wider than you need, so try this

```
With cell
    .WrapText = True
    .IndentLevel = 1
    .ColumnWidth = 255
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. It works, although resizing the columns makes additional flickering on screen.

Comment: To avoid flicker set screenupdating to false while the code runs